# Difference between ないからこそ and もいないんだから in practice question

Tags: grammar, jlpt

I haven't made sense of the answer to the following question.

> 試験の点が悪かったことを母に伝えると、「ちゃんと勉強( ) 、良い点をとろうなんて無理でしょう」と言われてしまった。
>
> a) してはいけないのに
>
> b) していないからこそ
>
> c) してもいないんだから
>
> d) しようとしていながら

The correct answer according to the book is `c)` however I can't figure out why it shouldn't be `b)` as both sound identical to me in English (Every time I tell my mom about bad grades on an exam, she says: "**If you don't even study**, of course, getting good grades is impossible!")

What would be the difference between `b)` and `c)`? The book only explains why `c)` is the answer without any context on the rest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole sentence becomes weird with the added こそ. The nuance between the first part of the sentence doesn't match with second part. からこそ is more commonly used to explain a positive reason:

誰もこのコースに出願していないからこそ、あなたは今すぐに入るべきだ。

Nobody has applied for the course yet so that's why you should be able to enter right away.

In your question/example, してもいないんだから is matching with your translation.
"She said, If you don't even study seriously, of course getting good grades is impossible."